# The current Dart SDK version is 2.15.1 in flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm getting this error for a very long time.

[image]

I tried uninstalling vs code
flutter clean
and reupdating the flutter SDK version.

even after that no success. I'm new to flutter and help me to solve the error

[image]

Comment: If my answer helped, remember to accept the answer to close it.

Answer (score 0):

Highest dart version on flutters stable channel is `2.17.6` and on beta channel it is `2.18.0`. To use dart SDK `2.19.something` I'm guessing you'd have to step up on flutters master channel.

IF you want that, run:

```
flutter channel master
flutter upgrade
```

But why do you have such high sdk requirements in your `pubspec.yaml` ? Maybe this is enough? I'm thinking that it should be... so just update your `pubspec.yaml` file

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.15.1 <3.0.0"
```